# Escaping $ dollar sign in CMake

Tags: cmake, escaping, post-build-event, dollar-sign

I'm trying to run a post build command in CMake 3.1.1 via:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
   TARGET mytarget
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND for i in `ls *` \; do echo \$i \; done \;
```

However, the $i variable is evaluated to nothing although I escape the dollar sign. According to logs the command is evaluated to:

```
for i in `ls *` ; do echo  ; done ;
```

I tried without escaping the dollar sign, but it led to the same problem. Double slash didn't work either. Now I'm puzzled...

Can you suggest a way to run a  command that uses dollar signs?

P.S. This was just an example. My actual command is slightly more complicated and I don't think I can work it out without using dollar signs.

Comment: Try this: echo \'$i'

Comment: That's what I get:   Syntax error in cmake code at

   .../CMakeLists.txt:210

  when parsing string

    \'$i'

Comment: In bash, we need to use -e option of echo for escape to take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, it fails even at the CMake compilation level

Comment: and what if you add `VERBATIM` to the `add_custom_command` argument list?

Answer (score 10):

You should use 'make' style escape with double dollar sign:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
   TARGET mytarget
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND for i in `ls *` \; do echo $$i \; done \;
)
```

Related links:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html

https://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg11302.html

Answer (score 6):

Use a [bracket quote](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument):

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
   TARGET mytarget
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND [=[for i in `ls *`; do echo $i; done]=]
)
```

Comment: Very nice, did not know about this quoting method!