# Substitute compile time macro from environment variable

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

How to set compiler macro from environment variable during compile time, i.e. when make is run (not when it generated), equivalent line to

```
g++ main.cpp -DFOO="${FOO}"
```

The usage is something like this:

1. Run cmake (only once).
2. Set the environment variable.
3. Run make and build a binary that uses the environment variable's value.
4. Change the environment variable and rebuild. New binary should use new value of the environment variable.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea in the long run: your builds will depend on the value of this environment value... What do you need it for?

Comment: xy problem? Sounds like you want to work around some limitation of cmake? Which one?

Comment: According to [escaping dollar sign in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584348/escaping-dollar-sign-in-cmake) it might work with `$$`.

Comment: 1) @Friedrich `\$` should work in general but maybe not here. 2) pic11, I agree with Botje. Why not rely on the environment variable being set at _configure time_ instead of _build time_? In which case you'd use [`$ENV{VARIABLE_NAME}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [`(CMAKE_)<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER_LAUNCHER) for this purpose, but I strongly advise against doing this, since the generated project won't be able to tell that recompilation of your sources is required. Furthermore if a environment variable is involved, it's not trivial to rebuild the project with the last configuration. Furthermore building only parts of the project is made basically impossible when using the environment variable; it's difficult to tell, which part of a project was compiled with a given value of a environment variable.

Instead I recommend adding a cmake cache variable that could be adjusted by simply reconfiguring the project which does result in cmake making the necessary updates to ensure a recompilation of the files the preprocessor define applies to.

```
...

set(MY_EXE_FOO "bar" CACHE STRING "The value to use for the FOO preprocessor define for my_exe")

add_executable(my_exe main.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(my_exe PRIVATE "FOO=${MY_EXE_FOO}")
```

Usage:

```
# set up with default (you could pass -D MY_EXE_FOO=... immediately to change the default)
cmake -S source_dir -B build_dir
cmake --build build_dir

# reconfigure the cmake project changing the define from bar to baz
cmake -D MY_EXE_FOO=baz build_dir
# rebuild with the new configuration
cmake --build build_dir
```

Note: You're even able to set up multiple build dirs for your project in parallel. (This assumes no files are generated to the source tree by any of the cmake logic involved.)

```
cmake -D MY_EXE_FOO=bar -S source_dir -B build_dir_bar
cmake -D MY_EXE_FOO=baz -S source_dir -B build_dir_baz
cmake --build build_dir_bar
cmake --build build_dir_baz
```